# R: duration of a sound file - sound package duration function returning incorrect value

Tags: r

I am trying to retrieve the duration of a sound file with ".wav" extension. I am using the duration function from the sound package to retrieve the duration. The documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sound/versions/1.4.5/topics/duration) says that the function should return the duration of the file in seconds, but I get a different value.

So I have two questions:

(1) Am I getting something wrong here or is the package somehow not working properly?

(2) How else can I get the duration of a wav file?

--- EDIT to include further info---

[image]

and here is the code:

```
sound::duration("afstandsbediening.wav")
[1] 0.0003401361
```

I would ideally like to have the duration with precision up to millisecond units.

--- EDIT 2 for more details---

Here is an example of another sound file which is less than one second long. The length property shows 0 seconds.

[image]

R returns:

```
sound::duration("aansteker.wav")
[1] 0.0002494331
```

But the duration of the sound file is: 0.996 seconds

[image]

The duration of the *afstandsbediening* sound file is 1.06 seconds

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: So your duration works fine and it is just a matter of how to round your small duration value. Windows file info just round up (ceiling) to a second, compare with `ceiling(0.0003401361) # [1] 1` or `signif(0.0003401361, 2) # [1] 0.00034`

Comment: I do not think this is true. This sound is more than a second long and it is being rounded down. I have other similar sounds which are less than one second long. For them the length property shows 0 seconds. In either case, I expect the digits after the decimals in the output of the duration command to reflect the duration of the sound file in milliseconds, but this is not what is happening.

Comment: I have added more info to the question above

Comment: this probably means the tool where you see a longer duration plays or is set at a different sample rate as your file. There is a nice tool actually https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-duration-calculator/ and you can see there if you change the sample rate smaller than set in the wav file the duration will increase. In the sounds library you can also use `sounds::sample(s)` to get all information of your file

Comment: updated my answer, in short check all file info and check at what rate you played the file giving the longer duration.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. (1) How can I check what quality the file is in. All of the information I see in the properties of the file I have posted above. (2) Regardless of which player I play the file in by default, I see the same length - windows media player, audacity, praat. So, why is R recognising some other rate of playing the same file?

Answer (score 1):

**update**

Ok after some more info in the comments lets take a look at this file.

```
s <- loadSample("file_example_WAV_1MG.wav")
duration(s)
[1] 33.53

bits(s)
# [1] 16
channels(s)
# [1] 2
rate(s)
# [1] 8000

# get file size
file.info("file_example_WAV_1MG.wav")$size
# [1] 1073218
```

Now go to this tool / calculator https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-duration-calculator/

[image]

This all looks good right at least it corresponds with the duration given by  R based on the other params.

But take a look what happens if you play the file on a different sample rate. I changed it from 8KHz to half of it, so 4 KHz and now we see your duration "play time" is doubled.

this strongly indicates that somehow you expect a duration that is played on a different rate than the rate of the file itself.

[image]

So now to your "aansteker" (lighter)
`0.995510 / 0.0002494331 # [1] 3991.1` is almost 4000 times longer that it takes. Might it be possible that you have a file 48KHz (CD quality) and play it at 4KHz? That would make your duration exactly 4000 times longer.

**first answer**
The library works perfectly fine.

```
library(sound)

s <- loadSample("file_example_WAV_1MG.wav")

duration(s)
# [1] 33.53
```

File info of the file on my machine (windows)

[image]

Or just create a sound sample and check the duration

```
s <- Sine(440, 5)
duration(s)

# [1] 5
```

To reproduce your issue, make sure you show the code, show the file info of the file you want the duration of and what your output is and what it was supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited the question to show properties of the file and the R output that I got. Also, I am hoping to get some more precision on the duration, i.e. in order of 1 ms. How is that possible?